# Jenkins pipeline send zip files in a website

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I would like to send my results from `Jenkins` to another website. The files are available in `zip`. Is there anybody who can give advice, what can i use to realize this ? I wrote my pipeline in groovy

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to help if you describe the authentication on the website you will upload to. If it is basic auth, curl will still be a valid option. If you first need to obtain a session token/bearer token - a little more work is needed (but easily doable in groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [curl](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76) in the jenkins job to upload the files.

Comment: But i have to authorized me in the website at first.

Comment: Yes. If you don't have permissions to upload on the website, how it is supposed to work?

Comment: I have permissions but i look for a method, how can i write this.

Comment: Check the Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-UploadingandDownloadingFiles). This might help in avoiding any custom implementation.